# Javascript continuing after another page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how (if even possible) to keep my javascript running after i've continued to the next page.

My situation:
Javascript clicks next button.
I'm now on a new page.
But the javascript stops running and all my functions/variables are gone.

I want to be able to push the button with javascript and then continue running the code that comes after that .click() part.

If its not possible can you maybe suggest a way to do this programmaticly?

Comment: Sounds like you need to write a "one page app" and use the history api.

Comment: You can do this using AJAX.

Comment: What is the code that you need to execute supposed to accomplish? depending on this question, different solutions might be appropriate. but in general an ajax call to some kind of server-side endpoint seems appropriate

Comment: Basically i'm trying to make a script that can check mark the person I want to vote for and hit next. Then hit done. Then go back 2 and repeat. I can do the clicking but I need the javascript to continue over the 3 pages for it to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

Once you leave the page, any JavaScript running on that page will also stop running.

You have two options.

1. Store any variables or settings you need using cookies, and continue running the same script on the next page.
2. Don't *actually* leave the page.  You can use AJAX to load new information on the page, or perhaps change part of the page content using an `IFRAME` while the host page continues to load.

Answer (score 0):

As @mike-edwards has said in the comments, you need a single page app.
You can use frameworks like [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) or [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) to make your life easier.

As you said, whenever a new page loads in the browser, all your variables etc from the previous page will be lost. The only way to preserve your variables is to not change the page. You can do this using these frameworks and the [HTML5 History](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) infrastructure.

With AngularJS, history support comes out of the box. As far as I know, Knockout.js does not have history API support so you would need to use another JS plug-in like [Davis.js](http://davisjs.com/) for that.